# Is there an embeddable Webkit component for Windows / C# development?

Tags: .net, com, webkit, gecko

I've seen a few COM controls which wrap the Gecko rendering engine ([GeckoFX](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/), as well as the control shipped by Mozilla - [mozctlx.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147/is-it-possible-to-embed-gecko-or-webkit-in-a-cnet-win-form-just-like-a-webview)). Is there a wrapper for Webkit that can be included in a .NET Winform application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a WebKit-Sharp component on [Mono's GitHub Repository](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp).  I can't find any web-viewable documentation on it, and I'm not even sure if it's WinForms or GTK# (can't grab the source from here to check at the moment), but it's probably your best bet, either way.

Comment: I was unsuccessful trying to get this to build on Windows a few weeks ago, but would be interested if someone else could get this to build.

Answer (score 42):

I've just release a pre-alpha version of **CefSharp** my *.Net* bindings for the *Chromium Embedded Framework*.

Check it out and give me your thoughts: https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp
(binary libs and example available in the downloads page)

**update**:
Released a new version, includes the ability to bind C# objects into the DOM and more.

**update 2**: no-longer alpha, lib is used in real world projects including Facebook Messenger for Windows, Rdio's Windows client and Github for Windows

Comment: Great! WPF version is over there!

Comment: Sadly, it's Windows-only.

Comment: @cubuspl42 checkout the CefGlue project which can run cross-platform as it uses P/Invoke instead of C++/CLI for its interop.

Comment: 2020 and CefSharp is still maintained. That is a big win.

Comment: I can't get the webforms examples to run

Comment: Was able to use CefSharp in WinForms app handling TDAmeritrade OAuth2 to have user enter their credentials to get the token from the redirect URL.

Answer (score 39):

Haven't tried yet but found [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) on SourceForge. It was moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/webkitdotnet).

**Warning:** Not maintained anymore, last commits are from early 2013

Comment: I got this working fine a few months ago.  Seemed to work well.

Comment: This project is no longer maintained -- I couldn't get anything to compile under Visual Studio 2012, nor does it have an up-to-date implementation of WebKit.

Answer (score 13):

[Berkelium](http://berkelium.org/) is a C++ tool for making chrome embeddable.

[AwesomiumDotNet](http://awesomiumdotnet.codeplex.com) is a wrapper around both [Berkelium](http://berkelium.org/) and [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/)

BTW, the link here to [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/) appears to be more current.

Comment: Berkelium is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 7):

> There's a WebKit-Sharp component on Mono's Subversion Server. I can't find any web-viewable documentation on it, and I'm not even sure if it's WinForms or GTK# (can't grab the source from here to check at the moment), but it's probably your best bet, either way.

I think this component is CLI wrapper around webkit for Ubuntu. So this wrapper most likely could be not working on win32

Try check another variant - project [awesomium](http://princeofcode.com/awesomium.php#download) - wrapper around google project "[Chromium](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/chromium/)" that use webkit. Also awesomium has features like to should interavtive web pages on 3D objects under WPF

Answer (score 6):

There is OpenWebKitSharp, a fork of WebKit.NET 0.5 and very advanced. Details:
http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this using CefSharp (which uses [chromium browser](http://www.chromium.org/Home)).

Here are a couple posts that show this in action:

- [Running Chrome inside O2](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/running-chome-inside-o2.html)
- [Video: Installing and running CefSharp (C# Chrome with WPF Browser)](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/video-installing-and-running-cefsharp-c.html)
- [Video: Running Chrome Natively in O2 and VisualStudio](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/video-running-chrome-natively-in-o2-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

The Windows version of Qt 4 includes both WebKit and classes to create ActiveX components. It probably isn't an ideal solution if you aren't already using Qt though.

Answer (score 1):

try this one http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/
hope it ain't dupe
or this one i think is better
http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/