# WPF Webbrowser control disable drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to disable dropping items like notepad, word etc on to a System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control in WPF.
**I have tried various options like** 
`AllowDrop="False"` - Does not work.
Tried to catch events like Drop, PreviewDrop, DragLeave, PreviewDragLeave, PreviewDragOver, PreviewDragEnter - None of these events fire when I drop items on the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Probably you can try implementing IDocHostUIHandler mentioned in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051892/webbrowser-dragdrop and then override the behavior.

Comment: No. That does not help in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the constructor or Xaml to create the following method will stop the drag from changing the webbrowsers current state:

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // The WebBrowser control is checking the Uri 
    if (e.Uri.ToString() != "Place your url string here") //ex: "http://stackoverflow.com"
    {
        // Uri is not the same so it cancels the process
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Info: `if (!e.Uri.IsFile) MailManager.FileManager.OpenExternalLink (e.Uri)` - Use "IsFile" to differentiate local drag & drop provided file paths from actually clicked or navigated hyperlinks. Also make sure to check `if (e.Uri != null)`, because if it is null, the navigation might be a normal loading of HTML-code or any other intended navigation. `e.Cancel = true;` will cancel any navigation that is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, none of the Drop event are fired, and it seems like the native browser control is very limited which leaves you with two possibilities:

- Either user another browser control like [wpfchromium](http://wpfchromium4.codeplex.com/),
- Or define a transparent popup in top of the browser and handle
  the drop even within it

:

```
<WebBrowser Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="wbBrowser"/>
    <Popup  Opacity="1" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="True" Placement="Center" 
     PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=wbBrowser}" >
        <Border  Background="Black" Opacity="0.01" 
         Width="300" Height="300">
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

This solution ain't pretty at all and needs also more logic to [handle when the popup's parent control moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600218/how-can-i-move-a-wpf-popup-when-its-anchor-element-moves)..

...you may also find this solution helpful, if your main content is html:

[How to disable drop on wpf webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266045/how-to-disable-drop-on-wpf-webbrowser-control)