# VB.net web browser question

Tags: vb.net

making a web browser on vb.net is depending on your internet explorer. How can I customize it so it will depend on mozilla. Please any suggestions or recommendations.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are making a website in VB.NET that starts in Internet Explorer, and you want to start it in FireFox instead?

To change the default browser in Visual Studio, Right Click a web form -> Browse With... -> Choose FireFox and click "Set As Default".