# Alternatives to the .NET WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, browser, geckofx

I'm developing a .NET 2.0 WinForms application.  It previously included the standard Microsoft ActiveX WebBrowser control, but I'm investigating alternatives.

What I need to do:

- Use the WebBrowser as a standard web browser control in the application
- Be able to use it in the background too- e.g., create the control, render the webpage and output the result to an image (using .DrawToBitmap), without the control ever being attached to a form.
- Hook into various events in the lifecycle- mainly DocumentCompleted.
- Webpages can be loaded (or reloaded) every 30 seconds or so, either through a new instance of the control or using the existing control.  The application can remain running for long and indefinite periods of time.
- Must work with .NET 2.0.  No 3.0+ or WPF stuff.

The only three controls I've been able to find so far all have rather critical issues that prevent me from going forward:

- Microsoft ActiveX WebBrowser - Has a huge memory leak that makes it unsuitable for running for long periods of time.
- WebKit.NET - As far as I've been able to establish this has to be attached to a form before any rendering is done, making it useless for the thumbnail generation piece.  Also seems to suffer from memory leaks.
- GeckoFX - Works best for me, but does not properly support threading (which is critical for the thumbnail generation piece).

Any other alternatives out there?

Comment: what do you mean by "not properly support threading" I think some workaround can be created

Comment: There is an Xpcom.Initialize call that may only be called once in GeckoFX.  From what I've been able to gather once you call that method in a thread the GeckoWebBrowser control becomes bound to that thread- doing anything with a GeckoWebBrowser in any other thread results in COM errors.

Comment: as a workaround you can spawn processes that will encapsulate GeckoFX

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been reading and keeping as an idea in the back of my head.  Sort of a last resort- the main project is already ridiculously complicated and I'd hate to add more moving parts as external processes to the mix.

Comment: Hey! I have an idea! You can try putting it in different AppDomains, it might give same benefits as separate processes and have much smaller overhead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Can you embed WebKit.Net in a form that's shown way off the visible area of the screen?

You might also look at Mono.WebKit or Mono.Mozilla, though I've never used any of these.

Comment: I tried a couple tricks like that with WebKit but couldn't get it working.  Doesn't mean it isn't possible- I only played with it for an hour or two.  Intriguing idea with the Mono libraries though.  I'll play around with that and see if I can get anywhere.