# Alternative WebBrowser .Net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, browser

I have some problem using default WebBroswer with C#.

I'm making program in C# WindowsForm. I would have multiple "tabs" of "Broswer" and i need to change many things like UserAgent . 
I had problem to do this with default WebBrowser becouse the trick(found on stackoverflow) worked only for 1 page and dont for all session.

Olso i need JavaScript support.

My Question is : 
Is there another webBroswer that emulate multiple "tabs" of webBrowser , support javaScript (This is very important : i need disable Javascript for a website page that have Location Header ), and that it's possible  change UserAgent and so emulate all existing Browsers ? 
If answer it's not What kind of "real" browser could i use with My c# WinForm Program?

Regards

Edit: I already used GeckoFX but without good result (with JavaScript)

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome

Comment: Already seen that discussion and i didnt find anything useful. I already used GeckoFX

Comment: When I did my research for a similiar project, GeckoFX was the only feasible alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [awesomium](http://awesomium.com/).
You'll have to write some code yourself (including tabs) as it's just a framework.
However, I haven't come across anything on for .net that comes close and it should meet your requirements.

There is a free license for "Indie Companies" (if you made less than $100k), non-commercial use or evaluation & dev purposes.
Downside is, you wont get access to the source for free, I don't know if that's a deal-breaker for you or not.
[Pricing](https://awesomium.com/buy/)