# what ActiveX control implementing a web browser?

Tags: activex

I am coding an add-on using an existing SDK which has no webview-like component but allows for ActiveX controls.

So the only idea I come up with is find an ActiveX control implementing a web browser or at least **show** a web browser.

Is there such control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the IE activex control, it's full of memory leaks.

See this post for alternatives:

[Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

[FireBreath](http://firebreath.org) has a [WebView](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/tree/master/src/libs/WebView/Win) library that uses the IE activex control to embed a web browser inside a FireBreath plugin (which acts as an ActiveX Control on IE). You should be able to adapt it, assuming you're using C++.

Answer (score 0):

Finally find it.

**SHDocVw.WebBrowser** will do.

Usually the path is **C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll**