# C# Windows Form Web Browser flash dont work

Tags: c#, browser, flash

I'm trying to make inside my app mini web browser. But here is fault. It dont show Flash videos (swf).

Is any method how to repair this fail?

Comment: Winforms, Wpf, ? and what code are you using to instantiate your WebBrowser

Comment: Yes Windows Forms.. not WPF. Im using Designer to create WebBrowser

Comment: Show your Navigation Code.  i.e. WebBrowser1.Navigate("**?**");

Comment: U mean URL? http://test.glararan.eu/test2.php because i dont use something like this

Comment: I think your problem is something similar to this [link](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/ie7-embedded-webbrowser-control-swfpdf-93125.aspx)

Comment: I dont have IE... i deactivate it in Windows 7 Control Panel...and i just use them on install google chrome nothing more.

Comment: You are using ie7 when you use the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Hm.. and is any other method ... dll or something like this?

Comment: lookd at this [SO Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome) or you can use Process to start a URL with the default browser, it will not be embedded though.

Answer (score 0):

You can show flash videos in the windows webrowser control

To get it working you will need change the CPU type of your project to support x86 ( i.e. 32 bit) because the WebBrowser control provides a managed wrapper for the WebBrowser ActiveX control

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have Platform Target set to x86. So here problem isnt

Comment: @user1085907 Is flash installed also if you get any errors can copy/paste in post pls