# Display formatted content to the user?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing a tester-application that will be used to test some of our products. The testing process involves displaying instructions to the tester (who might not be a professionally trained IT expert). These instructions involve formatting and can may also contain pictures. What would be a good way to display these?

I've thought about using a WebBrowser control and pointing it to static some HTML, but after having some issues with it (the webbrowser control is using a different version of the rendering engine then the locally installed IE is, etc...) I feel like this might not be the best option.

An argument for the use of HTML is that I could use one of many templating engines to easily create the instruction-content without hassling with too much formatting.

Do you have any advice on what to use here?

Comment: You can embed WebKit or Gecko into your app insted of the Trident WebBrowser control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If winforms are not a strict requirement, you could try using [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) in a WPF application.

It should allow you to obtain all the layout you need, and you can also find some tools to convert to/from HTML (with some restrictions, of course).