# How to prevent popup, new tab, new window and message boxes in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, controls, webbrowser-control

Here is HTML code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload=function(){
    alert('hi');
    }//]]>  

</script>
```

Not only alerts, popups, new tab, new window but anything cause focus change.
By other words I don't want WebBrowser control to get focused or change current focus.

Looking for a solution that doesn't hurt any weppage( I need javascript enabled).

Comment: You will have to intercept the page load event for the browser control, parse the javascript for anything that generates a popup, alert, etc. and comment that code out. You will also have to do that for any javascript that is loaded from a URL. It has been a while since I used the webbrowser control, so I am not certain this is possible with the built-in control.

Comment: And there will be places where doing the capture will interfere with the web page.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Do you know if I can fix this issue with CEF or any other browser control ?

Comment: I don't know what CEF is. None of the other browser controls that I am aware of will do this.

Comment: There is a good page with browser control alternatives. [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you should implement `IProtectFocus`, but apparently there're issues with it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/211733a0-af84-4cc4-9851-2f19def7aedd/iprotectfocus-and-allowfocuschange-not-working-on-webbrowser?forum=winforms

Another option might be to implement a [`CBTHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), handle `HCBT_SETFOCUS` and reject it (return 1 to prevent it) if the window becoming focused is a child window of the `WebBrowser` object.

Disclaimer: I myself haven't tried either of the above.