# Changing webbrowser default

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I am facing another problem that has to do with the IE the web browser uses by default. Some computers aren't able to run the website properly and face errors, so I want to change the browser in something that will work on everyone. I tried shells, etc but I want the website to open on the webbrowser. Also the webbrowser doesn't have any buttons textboxes and I want that page by default.
Can anyone help?

Comment: duplicate of how to use Chrome, WebKit or Gecko as browser control: http://stackoverflow.com/q/790542/1070452

Comment: They don't give a valid answer to actually solve the problem.

Comment: It all depends on the installation of your users (the WebBrowser control uses the installed IE version). You should set some prerequisites for your application, like "minimum version of IE = X". Also make sure the WebBrowser control doesn't use an older IE compatibility mode (if IE8 is installed, it uses in some cases the IE7 compatibility).

Comment: Actually the one that tried to use it said he had IE 11 on windows 7 and got the cannot display webpage that had half of the url in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at my question on MSDN Forum on how to change which version of IE the WebBrowser control uses:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/982b343e-5829-4127-b207-da6d33671604/custom-webbrowser-control-changing-to-ie9?forum=vbgeneral#532fac5e-01f7-4447-9637-b44fd74beb4a

Comment: For now I'll use firefox (geckoFX) and I'll follow the question on MSDN. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

create a form called Form1 or just name accordingly, delete everything with its code and paste with below, now you will be surfing using the current installed IE.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateBrowserKey()

'Below code adds a custom useragent, adding a custom useragent does not change the actual engine...thats why we need to do all this coding.
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.whatsmybrowser.org", "_top", Nothing, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36")

'This goes to the website using default user agent.
   'WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.whatsmybrowser.org")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        RemoveBrowerKey()
    End Sub

    Private Const BrowserKeyPath As String = "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
    Private Sub CreateBrowserKey(Optional ByVal IgnoreIDocDirective As Boolean = False)
        Dim basekey As String = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString
        Dim value As Int32
        Dim thisAppsName As String = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe"
        ' Value reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
        ' IDOC Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        Select Case (New WebBrowser).Version.Major
            Case 8
                If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                    value = 8888
                Else
                    value = 8000
                End If
            Case 9
                If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                    value = 9999
                Else
                    value = 9000
                End If
            Case 10
                If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                    value = 10001
                Else
                    value = 10000
                End If

            Case 11
                If IgnoreIDocDirective Then
                    value = 11001
                Else
                    value = 11000
                End If
            Case Else
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.ToString & BrowserKeyPath, _
                                          Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe", _
                                          value, _
                                          Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveBrowerKey()
        Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserKeyPath.Substring(1), True)
        key.DeleteValue(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName & ".exe", False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: why you use IgnoreIDocDirective parameter?

Comment: That's not gonna work as you've declared browser user-agent on this line: `WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.whatsmybrowser.org", "_top", Nothing, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36")`
If you remove this line and then manually navigate to whatsmybrowser, you'll get IE, not Chrome.

**Nice try tho :P**