# Switch launched browser according to clicked URL on Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

- Our company use some in-house web systems for daily business operations. These systems are optimized to IE, and don't function properly when you access to those applications via Chrome or Firefox.
- I am using mattermost and GitHub Enterprise for development environment. These services limits functionalities when you access to those services via IE.
- I have to set the default browser to IE  according to guidelines in our company (and administrators can reset the default browser to IE).

So when I receive a mail that contains a URL of GitHub pull request, I have to launch Chrome, copy the URL in the mail, and paste it to addresses bar (you also have to close IE window if you clicked the URL by mistake).

I want Outlook to launch IE when I click the URL of the in-house web system, and launch Chrome when I click the URL of mattermost or GitHub Enterprise.

My question is: How can I change launched browser according to clicked URL on Outlook?

Comment: One approach (although I don't like it that much), is writing a bot that detects the active window. Based on which window is active switch the default browser by changing the registry setting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350930/changing-webbrowser-default. I'd recommend using the autohotkey or autoit languages to do something like this, however you could do it in VBA. However, I feel like someone may have a better approach. Best of luck.

Comment: If you can set Chrome as default browser on your machine then "https://www.ietab.net" is your solution. You can configure URLs with wildcards that you want to open in IE. I am using this extension since last one year and it is flawless.

Comment: @RaghuSodha Thank you for your comment, but it seems to have to change default browser from IE to Chrome. As I wrote in the question, my company uses a software asset management system, so the administrators can change default browser to IE silently and forcibly.