# how to change webbrowser control in c# from using Internet Explorer to mozilla or chrome

Tags: c#, wpf, class, browser

As Early version of IE such as IE7 and IE8 not support HTML5 so I want to change my 
webBrowser control in C# To mozilla firefox or google chrome.

**OR**

If it is not possible can we use DLL of mozilla or google chrome in wpf application.

Comment: Try GeckoBrowser or WebKit Browser...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)