# Visual Studio Web Browser javascript errors

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, web, visual-studio-2015

I am using the built in visual studio web browser. When I try to access store.steampowered.com on this browser I get this error

`Line: 863
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'`

and parts of the page don't work such as the scroll bars and the new on steam sections. I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this. Accessing the steam site is an essential part of my program.

Comment: Are you sure that this is Java and not Javascript? They are two very different languages.

Comment: It is javascript my bad I was not aware of the difference

Comment: See here for possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome