# WebBrowser control doesn't open some sites

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to open a website in WebBrowser Control. But it has some script error and after some click on Yes or No , finally doesn't show anythings.
I changed my IE version emulator to 10(2711) and 11(2af9) and `ScriptErrorSuppressed = True` and ... but this site didn't open anytime.
`webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://mdp.ihio.gov.ir/mdp/SAP");`

Comment: There's a bunch of things that can cause this, but in your case it might be that the page you are linking is using Sencha's Ext.js, which does not support IE7, which the WebBrowser Control defaults to IE7. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome

Comment: I changed my IE version emulator to 10(2711) and 11(2af9)