# Nothing happens when i try to open a website using web browser c#

Tags: c#

I am a rookie in C# and am attempting to make a program to open websites using `web Browser`. It works fine with Google, Facebook, and others but when I try to open site `https://shopee.ph/` nothing happens.

This is my code

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://shopee.ph/");
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: its checking browser and redirecting to https://shopee.ph/unsupported.html

Comment: Have you check the answer mentioned below?

Comment: maybe needs more features on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call

Answer (score 3):

This site https://shopee.ph/ is checking browser versions and if not supported then redirecting to [shopee.ph/unsupported.html](http://shopee.ph/unsupported.html). By default [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control is using IE7 which is not supported by your mentioned site.
There are couple of options to change WebBrowser's browser as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome) . I have tried one of them and working as expected. Below is the full code :

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!WBEmulator.IsBrowserEmulationSet())
        {
            WBEmulator.SetBrowserEmulationVersion();
        }

        webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://shopee.ph/");
    }
}

public enum BrowserEmulationVersion
{
    Default = 0,
    Version7 = 7000,
    Version8 = 8000,
    Version8Standards = 8888,
    Version9 = 9000,
    Version9Standards = 9999,
    Version10 = 10000,
    Version10Standards = 10001,
    Version11 = 11000,
    Version11Edge = 11001
}
public static class WBEmulator
{
    private const string InternetExplorerRootKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";

    public static int GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion()
    {
        int result;

        result = 0;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(InternetExplorerRootKey);

            if (key != null)
            {
                object value;

                value = key.GetValue("svcVersion", null) ?? key.GetValue("Version", null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    string version;
                    int separator;

                    version = value.ToString();
                    separator = version.IndexOf('.');
                    if (separator != -1)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(version.Substring(0, separator), out result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        }

        return result;
    }
    private const string BrowserEmulationKey = InternetExplorerRootKey + @"\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";

    public static BrowserEmulationVersion GetBrowserEmulationVersion()
    {
        BrowserEmulationVersion result;

        result = BrowserEmulationVersion.Default;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, true);
            if (key != null)
            {
                string programName;
                object value;

                programName = Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
                value = key.GetValue(programName, null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    result = (BrowserEmulationVersion)Convert.ToInt32(value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            // The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        }

        return result;
    }
    public static bool SetBrowserEmulationVersion(BrowserEmulationVersion browserEmulationVersion)
    {
        bool result;

        result = false;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, true);

            if (key != null)
            {
                string programName;

                programName = Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);

                if (browserEmulationVersion != BrowserEmulationVersion.Default)
                {
                    // if it's a valid value, update or create the value
                    key.SetValue(programName, (int)browserEmulationVersion, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                else
                {
                    // otherwise, remove the existing value
                    key.DeleteValue(programName, false);
                }

                result = true;
            }
        }

        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool SetBrowserEmulationVersion()
    {
        int ieVersion;
        BrowserEmulationVersion emulationCode;

        ieVersion = GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion();

        if (ieVersion >= 11)
        {
            emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version11;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (ieVersion)
            {
                case 10:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version10;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version9;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version8;
                    break;
                default:
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version7;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return SetBrowserEmulationVersion(emulationCode);
    }
    public static bool IsBrowserEmulationSet()
    {
        return GetBrowserEmulationVersion() != BrowserEmulationVersion.Default;
    }
}
}
```

Hopefully It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i copied the hole code and the the problem still on the same site , but with others it works fine.