# Color is not been updating in WinForms WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I tried to host an html file in an WinForms WebBrowser control but I could not see the header color being updated. Please refer the below image. If I opened in an Internet Explorer, the color is showing fine but it is not updating while hosting in the WebBrowser control

[image]

Below is the code I am using for style sheet. The code with **background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfecff 0%, #b4d5ff 100%);**  is not been updated in WebBrowser control. Why this is happeneing? and is it possible to fix this issue?

```
body {
background-color: #777777;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 9pt;
}

table { 
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 9pt;
background-color: #FFF;
}

h1, h2 {        
background: #b4d5ff;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfecff 0%, #b4d5ff 100%);
}
```

Below is the html code that I have used for testing.

```
<html><body><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" /></head>
<h2>Testing</h2>
<table>
<tr><td>text1</td></tr>
<tr><td>text2</td></tr>
<tr><td>text3</td></tr>
<tr><td>text4</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code will work with Internet Explorer and you don't need to use a different browser control. You just need to make `WebBrowser` control to use the latest IE version installed in your system without compatibility mode. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/3110834).

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is based on an old version of Internet Explorer that does not support `linear-gradient`.

You either need to use a fallback approach that works in IE, or switch to a different control that is based on a different HTML rendering engine with wider-ranging support for modern CSS.

Comment: Hi Cody. Thanks for your reply. Is there any other control you could suggest so that I can achieve this?