# Is it possible to integrate Google Chrome and Firefox with C# .NET Web Browser control without using Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

By default, the C# .NET web browser control uses the Internet Explorer rendering engine to display web pages. Can we change it to Chrome/Firefox Web Browser instead of Internet Explorer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Comment: check *CefSharp*

Comment: In the past I tested GeckoFx, which emulates Firefox, and CefSharp, for chrome, like Pranav Patel stated above. I do not think WebBrowser can be set to work with another browser other than IE