# jQuery not working inside a Web Browser Control for a Google App Engine standard page

Tags: jquery, json, google-app-engine, ms-access

I am trying to figure out why `jQuery` does not appear to be working when I embed the page within a web browser control in a Microsoft Access 2016 form.

I created a page using the Google App Engine standard environment.  The page uses `Symfony` with `Twig` as the template engine.  The page executes a `cURL` request and receives JSON data from the server.  `jQuery` is then used to populate various fields on the page.  Everything works perfectly on this page when it is loaded directly from a browser.  Here is a sample of the rendered page:

[image]

The problem arises when I try to display this same page inside a Web Browser Control on a form inside a Microsoft Access 2016 application.  The page appears to work because it correctly returns the same JSON data and displays it on the page, but for some reason the `jQuery` does not populate the text boxes like it does in a normal browser.  Here is a sample of rendered page from the Web Browser Control:

[image]

I know that I am calling the `jQuery` reference correctly because everything works fine from a normal browser tab, and there are a few other tests pages I created with `jQuery` elements working also.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the default browser in Access 2016 simply isn't fully compatible with JQuery.

As far as I can tell from a quick preview of the USER AGENT (Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729))

It seems to be a really ancient IE 7.0. I imagine you would have to look into how to upgrade the browser control of Access 2016.

See also: [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)