# how to print html content with embedded css, image and javascript?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to parse html content which contains css and javascript, and then print it without having the computer to display the print dialog using c# desktop program?

The html may contain javascript that manipulate the DOM. For example :

```
<html><body><h1>Title</h1><script>document.write(Math.random())</script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to load it into a [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2) object and then call the [Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print?view=netframework-4.7.2) method

Although if you don't like IE you might want to look at [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/790542/3805124) for alternatives.