# How to make a WebBrowser control wrap another browser in c#

Tags: c#, windows, webbrowser-control

I am currently using a WebBrowser control in c# and would want to change the browser used. I've seen another question on this forum where DotNetBrowser was suggered but being new to c# I don't know how to proceed in order to install the new file and use it.

I am a java developper trying to get into c#. Being used to coding in eclipse I dont know very much about visual studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control [wraps IE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.version?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_Version), it can't be used with another browser. You have to find a different control to use.

Comment: As mentioned in some answers, you can use the [WebView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.forms.ui.controls.webview?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable)
(Microsoft Edge). I use it on Windows 10/VS 2015