# trade webBrowser visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know some way to change the visual basic web browser, because there are some sites that do not open in it, I tried to update the default browser but still some pages of not open (such as the fanatics page, it opens but some parts of website are not loaded as login part, clothing part, etc)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is English only.

Comment: This is an English site. Please translate to English, or ask on https://pt.stackoverflow.com/, thanks!

Comment: sorry brow!!
i edit

Comment: [Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome?answertab=oldest#tab-top) - perhaps look for the more recent answers in there.