# Is there any way to launch entire React application with all JS files through Web Browser control in WPF? Java scripts are not gettin loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I am using .NET WPF WebBrowser control in our application to launch the whole react application in web browser control.
But when I run the WPF application It shows me the dialog box with javascript error and if you press yes-yes to all the questions then also It ended up showing nothing on the screen but the blank screen

This is my code

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost:3000/");
}
```

Where my react application is running on port 3000(Checked everything and running properly)

This is the dialog box shown when I run the application
[image: When I press yes , It opens another dialog box with different java script file error]

Second error for "2.aeaacf2c.chunk.js" file

Third error for "main.a60e0400.chunk.js " file

When I press "yes" for all , It ended up showing blank screen with no loaded JS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285650/1506454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF's legacy `WebBrowser` control uses Internet Explorer which is pretty much a dead product. It will not display a React page better than IE, which is to say, badly or not at all.

Please take a look at [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) or better yet [CEFSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/). (FYI I have no affiliation with either product). Either will suit your needs but I like CEFSharp better as it doesn't require the end user to install any dependencies. This is a big gotcha with WebView2.