# Is Google Chrome embeddable?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, activex, chromium-embedded, embedded-browser

I've asked myself if one can embed the google chrome browser engine in an own application. I'm using Delphi 2009. There's an IE ActiveX wrapper component delivered with the IDE. Also, there's a Firefox ActiveX component out there, but it's based on very old code.

I'd like to embed the chrome engine. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: it's open-source... anything is possible ;-)

Comment: I'd say there is, going by this: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9138419/Google_plug_in_puts_Chrome_inside_IE

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Google Chrome is basically WebKit layout engine + nice UI. And WebKit [can be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142184/is-there-an-embeddable-webkit-component-for-windows-c-development).

There's also [chromium embedded framework (CEF)](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef).

And finally, check out [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/).

Comment: CEF looks promising, as it would give you Chrome's out standing V8 JavaScript engine as well as WebKit rendering, but it looks like there isn't ActiveX support yet.

Comment: I don't think any of them will support ActiveX.  ActiveX is essentially just a smaller OLE or COM object.  The only browsers that support it are IE and it's derivatives.

Comment: Why use ActiveX? Not for plugins and not for the library. I hate this COMadness when all you really need is a library.

Answer (score 5):

Update 2:
A very good fit for this would be the new [Electron Shell](https://electron.atom.io/)

Update:
As a commenter points out under this answer, this is no longer supported. For good reasons I guess.

Recently Google released the Chrome Frame active X for MS IE
see if that helps

http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: Google Chrome Frame is no longer supported and retired as of February 25, 2014.

Answer (score 2):

I've just release a pre-alpha version of **CefSharp** my *.Net* bindings for the *Chromium Embedded Framework*.

Check out source or grab bins and give me your thoughts: https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp