# C++ Webkit as COM object

Tags: c++, com, webkit, activex

I would like to create a COM object from Webkit and use it as an ActiveX in VB6.

Does anybody have any idea where to start? 
I think it would be best to do this in C++ and then use the COM object in VB6 instead of trying to implement it directly in VB6.

Can anybody suggest where to start? I don't think there is already a solution for this.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/142184/2065121

Comment: Yes, it is related, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Which is why I didn't suggest it as a duplicate :-)