# How to display HTML text content in win form with clear background?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am trying to display HTML content from an access db in a couple different forms. I have been using the webBrowserControl but this doesn't seem to support transparent back color.

I downloaded the alphaBlendTextbox from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo which works great as transparent but it doesn't display html content and ends up displaying the html tags.

Anyone have an idea of what I could use or do to get the HTML content to be displayed with a transparent background so that the background image or color of the form is displayed.

Comment: Is this not possible? Assuming someone has created a custom control for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use WebKit or any other component in your windows form as different webbrowser component. There are already some questions posted in SO. Like [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/142184/3761928) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

Comment: Don't know of any other controls that will display HTML content. It's mostly LI tags which I want to keep the LI format of a list style etc. Do these webkit components support transparent backcolor? I will not be setting this via css or anything in the DB as its not there. I just need the component, controller etc to have transparent background.