# Firefox C# Wrapper/Control

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a Firefox/Mozilla control for embedding the firefox browser in a C# .net application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have the Gecko rendering engine in the form of [GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/).

To quote Google Code:

> GeckoFX is a Windows Forms control written in clean, commented C# that embeds the Mozilla Gecko browser control in any Windows Forms Application. It also contains a simple class model providing access to the HTML and CSS DOM.

Comment: You'll also find mention of a Mozilla ActiveX control, but that doesn't appear to have been updated since 2005.

Comment: Also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147/is-it-possible-to-embed-gecko-or-webkit-in-a-c-net-win-form-just-like-a-webview

Comment: yeah i saw that activex control, but that is old and not supported

Comment: I hear that GeckoFX doesn't support javascript or jquery or ajax.

Answer (score 4):

Even better, there is a fork by **hindlemail**, actively updated DLL for .Net, here: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/.
Currently, there are available versions corresponding to Firefox's version 10 and 11.