# WebBrowsing with different browsers in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

I need to build a small application to compare site rendering in different browsers in different resolutions.
First I need to support IE, FF, Chrome and user will choose to preview her site in different resolutions. 
WebBrowser control do not offer me this.
Can you tell me is there any control or library to solve this problem in C#, .Net?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow itself provided some options.

I'd say you can put each one of the following into a TabControl, so the user can easily choose and switch view.

- For Internet Explorer, stock WebBrowser control should do.
- [Firefox Wrapper (GeckoFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306484/999042)
- [Chrome wrapper (Webkit.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141684/999042)