# Vc++ 6.0 MFC how to open a webpage using firefox browser and not internet explorer

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to open websites using Firefox browser control  inside VC++ 6.0 MFC Application. currently i can open web page only using internet explorer.please give me solution for opening in Firefox browser control.(i do not want to open new window or another application)

[Mozilla ActiveX control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm)[^]
i tried this Old active x control.but its not working for all web pages

Link to [Page loaded Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whr7U.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I embed firefox in a GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611906/how-can-i-embed-firefox-in-a-gui-application)

Comment: Unlikely to get any implementation with compiler support for a compiler, that is almost 2 decades old.

Comment: @zett42 i ask only for VC++ 6.0 MFC application

Comment: If you have access to a recent compiler, you could use it to create a DLL that does all the things required for embedding the browser and exports a few simple C functions that could be used by the VC++ 6.0 application. This way you won't be limited by the feature set of VC++ 6.0.

Comment: how to use recent compiler in vc++ 6.0 mfc .please give me  any examples or tutorials @zett42

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a URL in the default browser, you can try:

```
    ::ShellExecute(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), _T("open"), lpszURL, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.but this URL is opening  web page outside application .I want to open url  inside application.
for examples i tried 
m_WebBrowser.Navigate(url, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
but I am getting page load error here is error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whr7U.jpg

Comment: but I am getting page load error here is error message i.stack.imgur.com/Whr7U.jpg (in Internet explorer 8 only)