# How to build a web design program in C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I would like to build my own html gui editor, but I can't figure out the basic structure for the application.

Does anyone know of any sample code for building an editor? I would like to use Visual Studio 2010.

The part I don't know is how to build a wysiwyg area to display a page that is being designed.

Any help is appretiated

Comment: This is a very ambitious project.  What have you tried or investigated already?  Do you have a specification for how the WYSIWYG editor should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most editors are based on the WebBrowser control that comes with Visual Studio. For more info see:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

Or if you are more adventurous there are also solutions involving WebKit and Gecko browser engines discussed here:

[Is it possible to Embed Gecko or Webkit in a Windows Form just like a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147/is-it-possible-to-embed-gecko-or-webkit-in-a-windows-form-just-like-a-webview)

Comment: Which in itself is terrible since you end up with code that is targeted at the least standards compliant browser out there. There needs to be a way to easily wrap Webkit into a .net app.

Answer (score 0):

There is also MSHTML : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753630(VS.85).aspx

> The editor provided with MSHTML offers
>   a "what you see is what you get"
>   (WYSIWYG) HTML editing environment
>   with a rich set of capabilities. It
>   can be activated from C++, Visual
>   Basic, and script. You can use a
>   number of techniques to customize the
>   MSHTML Editor. These techniques are
>   available in C++ only.

Here is a .net wrapper: http://www.itwriting.com/htmleditor/index.php

> The HTMLEditor is written in C#.
>   Unlike the .Net webbrowser control, in
>   versions prior to .NET 2.0, this is
>   not an ActiveX control. Rather it is
>   an ActiveX Document. Even if you are
>   not interested in MSHTML, you may be
>   interested in the HTMLEditor as an
>   example of advanced .NET / COM
>   interop. It's also not suitable for
>   embedded web browsing - use the
>   ActiveX for that.
>
> However, it is a pretty cool control.
>   It allows editing as well as read-only
>   display, supports advanced features
>   like print templates and edit
>   designers, gives easy access to the
>   HTML DOM, and lets you load HTML
>   simply by assigning a string to a
>   property.

Answer (score 0):

SO user [leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541/leppie) made a very nice editor [xacc.ide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xacc/).

Comment: Looks like a code editor. Does it support WYSIWYG HTML editing?

Comment: @madisonw: No, it's just a nice text-based editor.