# mozilla firefox activeX

Tags: firefox, vb6, activex, controls

I like firefox more than IE, so am looking for firefox webbrowser activeX control just like the IE webbrowse control to use in my vb6 project.

Where can i get it or can someone give me directive as to how to make/compile the gecko st code to activeX

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

Or this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Roll_your_own_browser_-_An_embedding_HowTo

Or even a similar question here on SO: [Is it possible to Embed Gecko or Webkit in a Windows Form just like a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147/is-it-possible-to-embed-gecko-or-webkit-in-a-windows-form-just-like-a-webview)

Having said all that, I would suggest upgrading from VB6 -- My guess is that you won't find anything that will work with VB6: pretty much anything that's been written in the last five (even ten?) years is going to need .NET or other libraries that VB6 won't be able to deal with.

Comment: .Net required for Firefox? Pretty much all new Windows APIs work fine (or better) in VB6. The point is there are people actively using it.