# Firefox command line print

Tags: windows, firefox, printing, vb6

Have a requirement to print html or html from vb6 application using only firefox as we have already for IE. So, need command to print using firefox.exe.

Something like this `firefox.exe -print http://www.google.com` which is not working. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would you like to print? An arbitrary web page or some html file you are creating before? Could you elaborate on *which is not working*?

Comment: You may automize your workflow with `xdotool`: [Save firefox webpage with xdotool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612485/save-firefox-webpage-by-xdotool/612510#612510)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for a `-print` command line switch. See [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Browser) for the different command line switches supported for the Firefox browser. Support for such functionality would most probably have to be implemented [through an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Command_Line).

If no [extension exists](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=print%20from%20command%20line&platform=windows) that currently offers what your looking for, a Google search yielded this mozillaZine forum thread: ["Printing to file from Commandline?"](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2729795) You could have a look at the discussion, or download and modify the referenced add-on from the [source link](https://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2).

Or else, you could always create your own application (probably not in VB6) by embedding the Gecko layout, but since the Mozilla [killed the embedding API](https://lwn.net/Articles/436412/) a while back, you'll have a lot of integration work to do (or else you could [go with another layout engine like Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924255/how-to-embed-webkit-into-my-c-c-win32-application)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in webbrowser control to print html via IE: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?384076-Webbrowser-Control-Tip-and-Examples

If you must use firefox, there was a firefox active x control but I have not used it and dont know the status:

[mozilla firefox activeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707548/mozilla-firefox-activex)

or

http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm

or

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx

It also looks like there is a webkit floating around online (google it)