# .NET webbrowser proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, browser

I am searching for a method to set a proxy specifically to a form's webbrowser.
Currently I can set a proxy that is limited to my current process. 
But I want to explore multiple connections and forms each using a specific proxy. 
Web requests wouldn't work since I the website I will be using it does constant streaming. 
So downloading a page and loading it in a webbrowser wont be a solid solution.

Also the method im using right now is just importing the internetsetoption API.

Comment: What is the problem with your current method?

Comment: It only sets the proxy for the current application in total, not a specific form

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using Gecko (Firefox) or WebKit (Chrome,Safari) would solve your problem

From this question: [Is it possible to Embed Gecko or Webkit in a Windows Form just like a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26147/720223)

> http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/
>
> This is a nice .NET-wrapped version of Gecko

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set proxy on per control basis. .NET WebBrowser control is a wrapper for IE which uses system settings. If you already have a method which changes proxy for your application, I'm guessing you're making a system wide proxy change.

I'm in wonder how you even managed to control it on process basis :)

Comment: Its not system wide, and I specified that I am using setinternetoption to apply the settings.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use DotNetBrowser (Chromium-based) library. It provides the ability to set custom proxy settings without modifing the system global proxy settings.

Here is an article :

https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110051-configuring-proxy

And an example that demonstrates how to modify proxy settings without affecting global proxy settings.

https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110853-configuring-proxy