# How to use Gecko in C#

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx, geckosdk

I need a Gecko WebBrowser Control

I need a sample code or a link which explains how to use GECKO

If anyone has used Gecko, I could do with some advice

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147/is-it-possible-to-embed-gecko-or-webkit-in-a-windows-form-just-like-a-webview

Comment: Your answer is in your tags. What's the problem?

Answer (score 30):

**Edit:** (2023-11-6)

A most recent update can be found [here](https://medium.com/@xinyustudio/winform-how-to-add-an-embedded-web-browser-2019-7a5da106253d). Please upvote in that article if you find it useful :)

---

**Outdated:**

2023-11-6: Gecko's repo is empty.

Original tutorial with detailed snapshots can be found [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/embedding-web-browsers-in-winform-applications/#more-3695).

---

To embed Gecko browser in your winform application, you need:

- XulRunner: XULRunner is a Mozilla runtime package that can be used to bootstrap XUL+XPCOM applications that are as rich as Firefox and Thunderbird. It provides mechanisms for installing, upgrading, and uninstalling these applications. XULRunner can be downloaded [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx). Choose the version you like.
- GeckoFx .net assembly file, which you can download from [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx).
  Also choose the correct version which matches the XulRunner version.
- Unpack the GeckoFX-330.zip, you will get below files:

[image]

- Add references to the dlls as shown above, click browse and select the Geckofx-Core.dll and Geckofx-Winforms.dll

[image]
[image]

- In the toolbox, right click, and then select “Choose Item”, select Geckofx-Winforms.dll, and the Gecko winform control will be shown in the toolbox

[image]
[image]

- Drag a GeckoWebBrowser control to the winform designer, and let’s call it “browser”
  [image]
- In the form1.cs file, add below code:
  [image]

The line Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(@”..\xulrunner”); specifies where the xulrunner runtime is located. In this case, we put it into a folder (@”..\xulrunner”).

Now run the application, yeah~~~

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to write this answer, even though the  question itself is a couple of years old...

Comment: @David Thank you for quick and easy reference, during my implementation i am facing time out alerts for few sites. please refer the post if you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441947/c-sharp-winform-adding-geckofx60-64-60-0-47-as-browser-and-open-few-sites-shows

Answer (score 3):

You should check out http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/. To get some code samples see the [Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/wiki/GettingStarted).

Answer (score 0):

**Add gecko browser into Winform.**

**Short:**

1. Install Geckofx60.64 via nuget
2. set your project to x64
3. add this to Program.cs:

```
 Xpcom.Initialize(“Firefox64”);
```

4. drag geckowebbrowser control to your form.
5. add this to form1_load:

```
 geckoWebBrowser.Navigate(url);
```

That's it.

---

**Long:**

1. create a new Winform application in Visual Studio.  Mine is VS 2019 as of now.
2. Go to **Nuget**. search **Geckofx**. find the latest version, which is v60.

   Install  Geckofx60.64

   Once this is done, you will see some changes in your project:

   - A Winform control is added to your UI Toolbox
   - A list of DLLs are added to your bin/[debug |release]/Firefox folder

[image]

3. Drag a GeckoFX UI control to your Winform Designer, make it dock well as you wish:

[image]

4. You need add this  code to the Program.cs:

```
 Xpcom.Initialize(“Firefox64”);
```

Run the app, it should crash or pop up with an exception!

[image: crash image]

5. To solve this, you need to create a new **config for x64** architecture, like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

6. To open a Url in GeckoFX browser, use this function:

```
 geckoWebBrowser.Navigate(url);
```

Rebuild and run the app, hooray! It worked!

Note:
His answer was outdated. Copied the article here, From his link.

[Article by David Kou](https://medium.com/@xinyustudio/winform-how-to-add-an-embedded-web-browser-2019-7a5da106253d)  , [Example code at GitHub:](https://github.com/DavidKou/EmbeddedFirefoxBrowser/)